# SQLite db file don't exist in databases folder (cordova by using visual studio 2015)

Tags: android, visual-studio, sqlite, cordova

everyone,

Because I was using **visual studio 2015**, I use ddms bat file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools) to view db file, and I encounter a problem that I can't find my SQLite db file**(TodoDB.db)** in data/data/myAPP_Name/databases/ folder, there is only one db file named **barcode-scanner-history.db** instead of my db(**TodoDB.db**)

Also, I find a Datebase.db in data/data/myAPP_Name/app_webview/databases/ and I find out that the content inside the db file is schema of TodoDB.db

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>origin</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>description</td>
    <td>estimated_size</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>file__0</td>
    <td>TodoDB</td>
    <td>Todo manager</td>
    <td>10485760</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By the way, I use the following code to create a sqlite db :

```js
    var html5 = {};
        html5.webdb = {};
        html5.webdb.db = null;

    html5.webdb.open = function () {
        var dbSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // `enter code here`10MB
        html5.webdb.db = openDatabase("TodoDB", "1.0", "Todo manager", dbSize);
    }

    html5.webdb.createTable = function () {
        var db = html5.webdb.db;
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todoTable(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT, added_on DATETIME)", []);
        });
    }
```

and I call open():

```js
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#myPage", function (e, ui) {         
            //debugger;
            html5.webdb.open();
            html5.webdb.createTable();
          
            //========some other db operation========
            html5.webdb.deleteTodo();
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                html5.webdb.addTodo("test" + i);
            }                        
            //========================================
        });
```

How can I find my db file(**TodoDB.db**)

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post full code of how you are creating the DB? and this `OpenDatabase()` function you are using, is it from Cordova or it is from android SDK's default function?

Comment: @Darpan , I've already updated some code as above! thanks

Comment: Did you got your db?